# Using shell script which checks if the user has logged in twice into Unix server and displays the details of the users

Tags: shell, unix

Here I want to display logname of my system, if I logged in twice.
But displays many other lognames also.

```
v1=`who | wc -l`
c=`expr $v1 - 1`;
count=0
declare -a val
val=`who | cut -d" " -f1`
echo "$c"
temp=0
while [ $temp -le $c ]
do
if [ "{$val[$v]}" -eq `logname` ]
then
count=`expr $count + 1`

if [ $count -eq 2 ]
then
echo "`logname`, `uname`, `hostname`"
else
echo "No one";
fi
temp=`expr $temp + 1`
echo $temp
fi
done
```

Kindly check my code...

Comment: Is this code working? If it isn't you need to be specific about the problem to get any help here. If it is and you just want a review then this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: in addition to Etan's comment. Working means `no errors` **and** `producing the expected result` otherwise it would be **off topic** on CR.

Comment: @EtanReisner As I understand "But displays many other lognames also.", I guess that it's not working. Very unclear though.

Comment: iam getting output like this

Comment: tr682671
tr682952
tr683049
tr682860
tr683515
tr682888
tr682817
tr682885
tr524281
tr524284
tr683465
tr683343
tr682933
tr683367
tr524085
tr683146
tr683438[19]}: integer expression expected
19 times I am getting this much lognames